# I get an error calling yaml_parse() in PHP on Rocky

Tags: php, yaml

I am trying to decode and parse a base64 encoded YAML string with PHP.  Everything works great until I call yaml_parse.  Here is the entire programs (production will get the string from another source)...

```
$pdate = "LS0tIApwbGFzZWN0em9uZURheXM6IDMyNzY3CnBsYXNlY3R6b25lU3RhcnR0aW1lOiAwCnBsYXNlY3R6b25lU3RvcHRpbWU6IDE0NDAK";

$decoded = base64_decode($pdate);
yaml_parse($decoded, -1, $dCnt, $tzoneDetails);

print_r( $tzoneDetails );
```

When this runs the "PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function yaml_parse()" is thrown.

I have installed YAML like this...

```
dnf install libyaml
Last metadata expiration check: 0:18:01 ago on Wed 19 Jan 2022 09:52:20 AM EST.
Package libyaml-0.1.7-5.el8.x86_64 is already installed.
Dependencies resolved.
Nothing to do.
Complete!
```

I also added a yaml extension file in *php.d*  but I am not sure it is required.  I get the error both with and without the extension added.  I have restarted apache with each change...

```
; Enable yaml extension module
extension=yaml.so
```

Any ideas?

Comment: The YAML extension [is not bundled with PHP](https://www.php.net/manual/en/yaml.installation.php).

Comment: I tried to install YAML with "pecl install yaml" but this ends with "configure: error: Please install libyaml
ERROR: `/tmp/pear/install/yaml/configure --with-php-config=/usr/bin/php-config --with-yaml' failed" but as you see above it is already installed.